# difference between two SYSTEMTIME variable

Tags: c++, windows, systemtime

I want to get difference  between two SYSTEMTIME  variable. I saw someone asked this question here before, but he was told to convert both SYSTEMTIME structures to FILETIME..
Is there another way to get the difference?

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
```

---some code here---

```
  SYSTEMTIME st2;
  GetSystemTime(&st2);
```

**st-st2?**

Comment: Why can't you do what everybody recommends and convert the `SYSTEMTIME` to `FILETIME`?

Answer (score 22):

```
SYSTEMTIME operator-(const SYSTEMTIME& pSr,const SYSTEMTIME& pSl)
{
    SYSTEMTIME t_res;
    FILETIME v_ftime;
    ULARGE_INTEGER v_ui;
    __int64 v_right,v_left,v_res;
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&pSr,&v_ftime);
    v_ui.LowPart=v_ftime.dwLowDateTime;
    v_ui.HighPart=v_ftime.dwHighDateTime;
    v_right=v_ui.QuadPart;

    SystemTimeToFileTime(&pSl,&v_ftime);
    v_ui.LowPart=v_ftime.dwLowDateTime;
    v_ui.HighPart=v_ftime.dwHighDateTime;
    v_left=v_ui.QuadPart;

    v_res=v_right-v_left;

    v_ui.QuadPart=v_res;
    v_ftime.dwLowDateTime=v_ui.LowPart;
    v_ftime.dwHighDateTime=v_ui.HighPart;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&v_ftime,&t_res);
    return t_res;
}
```

Comment: If right is a few seconds earlier then left...then it looks like you get a really big time as your answer?  SYSTEMTIME is made of WORD members (unsigned), so it cannot represent negative time differences.

Comment: with modern C++ `ULARGE_INTEGER`s can be subtracted as is without copying them into `__int64`s

Answer (score 7):

[It says pretty clearly on the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> It is not recommended that you add and subtract values from the
>   SYSTEMTIME structure to obtain relative times. Instead, you should
>
> - Convert the SYSTEMTIME structure to a FILETIME structure.
> - Copy the resulting FILETIME structure to a ULARGE_INTEGER structure.
> - Use normal 64-bit arithmetic on the ULARGE_INTEGER value.

Why not do exactly that?

Comment: i wanted to avoid this. but, I'll do what you suggested. how do i deduct the two ULARGE_INTEGER structure i created?

Comment: You can just use a 64-bit int type for that. As also stated on MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383742(v=VS.85).aspx ): Your C compiler may support 64-bit integers natively. For example, Microsoft Visual C++ supports the __int64 sized integer type. For more information, see the documentation included with your C compiler.

Answer (score 6):

ft1 and ft2 are filetime structures

```
ULARGE_INTEGER ul1;
    ul1.LowPart = ft1.dwLowDateTime;
    ul1.HighPart = ft1.dwHighDateTime;

ULARGE_INTEGER ul2;
    ul2.LowPart = ft2.dwLowDateTime;
    ul2.HighPart = ft2.dwHighDateTime;


ul2.QuadPart -= ul1.QuadPart;
```

Difference in Milliseconds...

```
ULARGE_INTEGER uliRetValue;
    uliRetValue.QuadPart = 0;


    uliRetValue = ul2;
    uliRetValue.QuadPart /= 10;
    uliRetValue.QuadPart /= 1000; // To Milliseconds
```